# using URL parmater with conditional

Tags: conditionals

Inside this URL there is a parameter:

```
http://localhost/recipe?id=9
```

Is it possible to use this parameter `(id=9)` with a conditional, like a segment? Or to check if there is a parameter inside a URL or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily retreive GET and POST variables with the **Mo' Variables** add-on.

[Download from Devot-ee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables)
[Github repository](https://github.com/rsanchez/mo_variables)

For example, if your URL is `http://localhost/recipe?id=9`, you could use this code in your `recipe/index` template:

```
{if get:id == "9"}
  TRUE!
{/if}
```

You can also create default values for variables in the extension settings to test conditionals if no id parameter exists. For instance, if the default value for "id" is 0:

```
{if get:id != 0}
  ID EXISTS!
{if:else}   
  No ID here!
{/if}
```

This is useful for handling exceptions like if there is no value in the query string (`/recipe?id=`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex. Why using {if "{get:id}" == "9"} in place of {if {get:id} == "9"}. In this case what is the role  of the Quotation marks between {get:id}???

Comment: Using  {if "{get:id}" != ""} works fine, but without the quotation marks: {if {get:id} != ""} give a server error. I'm just curious to know why this error appears without the the quotation marks.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure why conditionals work without quotation marks sometimes and other times you need them. Testing `{if {get:id} == "9"}` works fine. So does {if get:id == "9"}. And even `{if {get:id} == 9}` if you only ever expect an integer as the value. But I usually try using quotes and curly braces as part of my troubleshooting process because they tend work more often especially for complicated logic. Reading thru this related question, it seems like there is not clear consensus on the issue: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/7/153

Comment: Turns out, it's fine to not use curly braces or quotes and you may even have befits from this in terms of the parse order so I'll update my answer.

Comment: Alex, thanks a lot for your explication and for the link. It's more clear now!!

Answer (score 1):

With mo' variables (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) you can get your get/post vars into early parsed variables you can then use in standard conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

The URL Helper add-on is also worth mentioning, and will give you access to the query string within your templates.